# JavaFx Fade In-Fade Out for TableView Row

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, desktop-application, fadein

This is my first question on stackoverflow so be kind :)

I'm making a currency rates desktop app. Using an api and every 10 seconds i am refreshing the table view.

I want to make fade in-fade out for each tableview row. When average value bigger then previous value that row will be green. If less, it will be red. Example is here;

https://examples.ext.net/#/SignalR/Basic/StockTicker/

I saw this but couldn't resolve how to implement my project;[Fade Transition via custom cell factory in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399214/fade-transition-via-custom-cell-factory-in-javafx)

Codes;

Currency.java

```
package model;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Currency {
    private SimpleStringProperty dovizKuru;
    private SimpleStringProperty alis;
    private SimpleStringProperty satis;
    private SimpleStringProperty ortalama;
    private SimpleStringProperty gunlukDegisim;

public Currency(SimpleStringProperty dovizKuru, SimpleStringProperty alis, SimpleStringProperty satis,
        SimpleStringProperty ortalama, SimpleStringProperty gunlukDegisim) {
    super();
    this.dovizKuru = dovizKuru;
    this.alis = alis;
    this.satis = satis;
    this.ortalama = ortalama;
    this.gunlukDegisim = gunlukDegisim;
}


public String getDovizKuru() {
    return this.dovizKuru.get();
}


public void setDovizKuru(SimpleStringProperty dovizKuru) {
    this.dovizKuru = dovizKuru;
}


public String getAlis() {
    return this.alis.get();
}


public void setAlis(SimpleStringProperty alis) {
    this.alis = alis;
}


public String getSatis() {
    return this.satis.get();
}


public void setSatis(SimpleStringProperty satis) {
    this.satis = satis;
}


public String getOrtalama() {
    return this.ortalama.get();
}


public void setOrtalama(SimpleStringProperty ortalama) {
    this.ortalama = ortalama;
}


public String getGunlukDegisim() {
    return this.gunlukDegisim.get();
}


public void setGunlukDegisim(SimpleStringProperty gunlukDegisim) {
    this.gunlukDegisim = gunlukDegisim;
}
```

}

Api service

```
package services;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import model.Currency;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class CurrencyRateServices extends Service<ObservableList<Currency>> {
    public ObservableList<Currency> apiResponse() throws IOException{

    
    
    StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder("https://api.yapikredi.com.tr/api/investmentrates/v1/currencyRates");
    URL url = new URL(urlBuilder.toString());
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    //Bearer 9e6f33ac-ddfc-4a5d-b55d-155a0f3f0e69
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "TOKEN");
    System.out.println("Response code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
    BufferedReader rd;
    if(conn.getResponseCode() >= 200 && conn.getResponseCode() <= 300) {
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    } else {
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    conn.disconnect();
    System.out.println(sb);
    
    ObservableList<Currency> currList= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    JSONObject obj2=obj.getJSONObject("response");
    JSONArray jsonArray=obj2.getJSONArray("exchangeRateList");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("minorCurrency").equals("TL")) {
            Currency currency = new Currency(
                    new SimpleStringProperty(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("majorCurrency") + "/"+ jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("minorCurrency")),
                    new SimpleStringProperty(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("buyRate")),
                    new SimpleStringProperty(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sellRate")),
                    new SimpleStringProperty(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("averageRate")),
                    new SimpleStringProperty(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("changeRatioDaily"))

            );
            currList.add(currency);
        }
        
    }
    
    return currList;
}

@Override
protected Task<ObservableList<Currency>> createTask() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Task<ObservableList<Currency>>() {
        protected ObservableList<Currency> call() throws Exception{
            return apiResponse();
        }
    };
}
```

}

MyController

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import application.DovizManager;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import model.Currency;
import services.CurrencyRateServices;
import view.ViewFactory;

public class DovizMainController extends BaseController implements Initializable{
    @FXML
    private TableView<Currency> dovizTableView;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Currency, String> col_DovizKuru;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Currency, String> col_Alis;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Currency, String> col_Satis;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Currency, String> col_Ortalama;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Currency, String> col_GunlukDegisim;

private ObservableList<Currency> crList;

public DovizMainController(DovizManager dovizManager, ViewFactory viewFactory, String fxmlName) {
    super(dovizManager, viewFactory, fxmlName);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    setUpFirstTableView();
    setUpTableView();

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}
public void setUpFirstTableView() {
    //ObservableList<Currency> crList = null;

    CurrencyRateServices crService=new CurrencyRateServices();
    try {
        crList=crService.apiResponse();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dovizTableView.setItems(crList);
    col_DovizKuru.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Currency,String>("dovizKuru"));
    col_Alis.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Currency,String>("alis"));
    col_Satis.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Currency,String>("satis"));
    col_Ortalama.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Currency,String>("ortalama"));
    col_GunlukDegisim.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Currency,String>("gunlukDegisim"));
    
    
}

public void setUpTableView() {
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10000), new EventHandler() {
        

        @Override
        public void handle(Event arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            CurrencyRateServices crService=new CurrencyRateServices();
            crService.start();
            crService.setOnSucceeded(e->{
                ObservableList<Currency> crListNew=crService.getValue();
                for (int i = 0; i < crList.size(); i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < crListNew.size(); j++) {
                        if(crList.get(i).getDovizKuru().equals(crListNew.get(j).getDovizKuru())) {
                            System.out.println("başlıklar aynı");
                            
                            if(crList.get(i).getOrtalama()!=crListNew.get(j).getOrtalama()) {
                                System.out.println("ortalamalar aynı");
                                if(Double.parseDouble(crList.get(i).getOrtalama())>Double.parseDouble(crListNew.get(j).getOrtalama())) {
                                    
                                    crList.get(i).setAlis(new SimpleStringProperty(crListNew.get(j).getAlis()));
                                    crList.get(i).setGunlukDegisim(new SimpleStringProperty(crListNew.get(j).getGunlukDegisim()));
                                    crList.get(i).setOrtalama(new SimpleStringProperty(crListNew.get(j).getOrtalama()));
                                    crList.get(i).setSatis(new SimpleStringProperty(crListNew.get(j).getSatis()));
                                    
                                    dovizTableView.getItems().set(i, crList.get(i));
                                } else {
                                    crList.get(i).setAlis(new SimpleStringProperty(crListNew.get(j).getAlis()));
                                    crList.get(i).setGunlukDegisim(new SimpleStringProperty(crListNew.get(j).getGunlukDegisim()));
                                    crList.get(i).setOrtalama(new SimpleStringProperty(crListNew.get(j).getOrtalama()));
                                    crList.get(i).setSatis(new SimpleStringProperty(crListNew.get(j).getSatis()));
                                    
                                    dovizTableView.getItems().set(i, crList.get(i));
                                    
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                        }else {continue;}
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                
            });



        }
        
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

}
```

}

Comment: not supported - you would need a custom skin with a custom VirtualFlow, don't expect it to be overly easy ;) And stick to java naming conventions, please (no underscores). Ahh .. seeing that you want to fade the color of a row: that probably can be achieved with a custom TableRow.

Comment: @kleopatra Hi thanks for your comment, underscores are old habits :) and yes i want to do that. Did you check the link i shared above "Fade Transition via custom cell factory in javafx"? Any thoughts about how can i implement that?

Comment: you are trying the n-th step before the(n-1) :) a) start with a decent tutorial on how to use virtualized controls (as TableView) (your data item implementation is completely wrong, we never replace a _property_, only its _value_)  b) once you are confident with the basics, go ahead to the fading - the answer in the referenced question should just work. If not, strip your code down to a [mcve] mind the __M__ (no backend needed, just a simple item with some state transition mockup)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking that isn't answered in the question you already linked.